# writing exception handler

Tags: sql, exception, null, handler

Im trying to create an exception handler to prevent null values from being inserted. I also want to make it to where if it is a null value being inserted then the original cost will display inside the message instead.

my two tables are..

```
create table pitem,
(item_id  number,
item_cost  number(10,2)
);
```

and..

```
create table pitem_audit
(item_id  number,
message  char(80)
);
```

and heres the procedure..

```
create or replace procedure update_item_cost
(iItemId INTEGER,
fNewcost NUMBER) AS
fCurCost NUMBER(10,2);
missing_cost EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
   select item_cost INTO fCurCost from pitem
   where item_id=iItemId;
   IF fCurCost IS null THEN
   RAISE missing_cost;
   ELSE
   UPDATE pitem SET item_cost=fNewcost
      where item_id=iItemId;
   END IF;
COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
     INSERT INTO pitem_audit VALUES (iItemId, 'Invalid Item identifier.');
     COMMIT;
  WHEN missing_cost THEN
     INSERT INTO pitem_audit VALUES (iItemId, 'Item cost is null.');/*<---heres where I want it to use the original cost of the item saying 'Null cost replaced by original cost of whatever the orignal was*\
     COMMIT;
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
     ROLLBACK;
     INSERT INTO pitem_audit VALUES (iItemId, 'Miscellaneous error.');
     COMMIT;
  END update_item_cost;
/
```

/*THIS IS THE BLOCK USED TO CALL THE UPDATE_ITEM_COST PROCEDURE AND ALSO HOW I ENTER THE VALUES FOR COST*\

```
DECLARE
 item_ident number;
 cost number;
BEGIN
 item_ident := 10;
 cost :='';
 update_item_cost(item_ident, cost);
END;
/
```

My question is how would I go about writing the exception handler to prevent null values from being entered..should I just do an ALTER TABLE statement and add a NOT NULL constraint? Also how would I get the message under the pitem_audit table to display 'Null cost replaced by original value of [original item_cost]'?

thanks in advance :D

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Getting any error? Please edit your question title with your problem.